# how to display a text on to to my view below my tabel view ,that single line text must be scrolling

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

i have a view in which i have tabel view and i want to set up a text scrolling from left to right in the bottom of my main view ,....

what abt if i am select navigation bar for solve this purpose?
can any suggest which i have choose to solve this....

any suggestions appreciated

Comment: I'm going to guess this is on the iPhone... If it is then you should tag it accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert footer into UITableView (simple UILabel with transparent background).
In Interface Builder just drag UILabel control on UITable bottom.

Or you can make it in code:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return @"My footer text";
}
```